# Running installed application with root on Android Emulator

Tags: android, root

I'm running Android Emulator with root access.

I install RootExplorer using adb install RootExplorer.apk

Install is OK

But when I launch RootExplorer it cannot display system folders. In eclipse log I can see permission denied...

I thought that all applications in Android Emulator run with root permissions..

How to launch apk with root permissions?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that all applications in Android Emulator run with root permissions..

It is not true. Just that emulator is rooted. It doesn't mean all application can happily run with root privileges.

You need **su binary** and **superuser app** to run app with root privilege.

Try this link:
http://abd-tech.blogspot.com/2011/05/test-root-apps-on-android-emulator.html

**Note:** It will not work for ICS emulator. Try for older versions like Gingerbread emulator.